# How do I pass data to a stacked bar chart in R?

Tags: r

I have a csv file where data is structured like this:

```
model,pass,fail
a,10,5
b,5,10
c,15,5
```

I want to make a stacked bar chart that would look like this:
[image: stacked bar chart]

I have tried to use the following code (data is the name of the imported csv file):

```
barplot(as.matrix(data), col=c("light green","light yellow"))
legend("topright", fill=c("light green","light yellow"), legend=rownames(data))
```

...but this puts the header names as data points. How should I pass "data" to the barplot function, so that each model (a,b,c) is a bar?

(since I'm new to R, I would rather not use any libraries like ggplot for now)

Comment: `barplot(t(data[,2:3]), names=data$model)` but you really should not consider base graphics a stepping stone. ggplot2 is based on the grammar of graphics and will help you think about plotting more logically.

Comment: Thanks! Why is there a comma in [,2:3]?

Comment: there is no row filtering needed and only selecting the 2 data columns

Answer (score 0):

```
> model <- c("a", "b", "c")
> pass <- c(10, 5, 15)
> fail <- c(5, 10, 5)
> dat <- data.frame(model, pass, fail)
> 
> library(ggplot2)
> library(reshape2)
> dat <- melt(dat)
Using model as id variables
> dat
  model variable value
1     a     pass    10
2     b     pass     5
3     c     pass    15
4     a     fail     5
5     b     fail    10
6     c     fail     5
> ggplot(dat, aes(x = model, y = value, fill = variable)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

[image]

If you don't want to use ggplot2 package, you can try

```
model <- c("a", "b", "c")
pass <- c(10, 5, 15)
fail <- c(5, 10, 5)
dat <- data.frame(pass, fail)
dat <- t(dat)
rownames(dat) <- model

barplot(dat, xlab = "Model", col = c("light green","light yellow")) 
legend("top", legend = rownames(dat), fill = c("light green", "light yellow"))
```

[image]

Comment: _"…I would rather not use any libraries like ggplot for now"_